# Drain making dripping sound after sink drains. No leaks

Tags: plumbing, drain, p-trap

Does anyone have an idea why after I turn off the water in my newly installed vanity, it begins making a dripping noise for approximately 5-15 seconds.

It's only a few drips honestly but none of the other drains in my home make this noise. I did the install and just want to make sure that it isn't a symptom of a greater issue, like the P-Trap siphoning out the residual water.

Drain was installed with the foam gasket included, considered plumber's putty.

There are no leaks visible in the P-Trap or the drain assembly. No smell of sewer gas. This shouldn't be driving me nuts but it is.

Parts:

P-Trap

https://www.homedepot.ca/product/os-b-plastic-1-1-2-p-trap-with-1-1-4-reducing-washer/1000120436

Tailpiece extension

https://www.homedepot.ca/product/os-b-brass-1-1-4-x-6-chrome-extension-tube-slip-joint-connect/1000120361

Drain

https://www.homedepot.ca/product/os-b-brass-lavatory-drain-with-clicker-closure-brushed-nickel/1000800313

Vanity

https://www.ovedecors.com/us/cliff-30-white.html

Comment: what do you mean by `after I turn off the water`? ... do you actually mean `after the sink finishes draining`? .... it is probably residual water dripping at the center of the drain where the popup plug attaches

Answer (score 1):

I have found this on many sinks while draining a little water backs up in the over fill drain and the water in there takes a little longer to drain out as it is not as open as the main drain (the deeper the water is in the basin the longer it may take to stop). About the only way to eliminate it would be to seal off the overflow drain. Some basin designs are worse than others but this is what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Cheers for the responses guys. I believe that the possibility of water being trapped in the overflow is the cause of this.

I still am concerned that maybe the water is being siphoned out.

I have a google youtube link with a video I took of it. Anything I should be really concerned about?

https://youtu.be/T80P8hF3T08

Comment: Evan, we're not a discussion forum and this shouldn't have been posted as an answer. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) and migrate this information to your question or to comments on specific answers.